# React - update session storage variable in one component when the dropdown in another component changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, session-storage

I have a dropdown in my navigation bar and would like to change the data of another dropdown in a different component by saving the value of the Nav dropdown in session storage.

The issue is when the dropdown in Nav bar is changed it doesn't reflect in the main app component and the **newData** doesn't get updated and remains the same

Nav component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortedTeams.length == 0) {
      setIsLoading(true);
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (selectedTeam == '') {
        setSelectedTeam(sortedTeams[0].teamName);
        sessionStorage.setItem('teamName', sortedTeams[0].teamName);
      }
    }
  }, [sortedTeams]);

  const handleSelectTeam = e => {
    setSelectedTeam(e);
    sessionStorage.setItem('teamName', e);
  };

          <DropdownButton
            id="dropdown-basic-button"
            variant="info"
            onSelect={handleSelectTeam}
            title={selectedTeam}
            className="displayInline"
          >
            {sortedTeams.map((value, i) => {
              return (
                <Dropdown.Item key={i} eventKey={value.teamName}>
                  {value.teamName}
                </Dropdown.Item>
              );
            })}
          </DropdownButton>
```

MainApp:

```
   const getTeamName = sessionStorage.getItem('teamName');
    const newData = [];

  useEffect(() => {
  if (sortedData.length > 0) {
    sortedData.map(sorted => {
      if (sorted.teamName == getTeamName) {
        newData.push(sorted);
      }
    });
  }
  }, [sortedData, getTeamName]);
```

Comment: Small thing to add. You don't need to have `removeItem()` from session storage and then `setItem()` afterwards. Just use `setItem()`  to set the same **key** teamName which will override the previous value you set.

Comment: ok. but do you have any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I believe this mainly happens because `MainApp` doesn't re-render itself when you change the drop-down value. Without more information on `Nav` and `MainApp` component structure, I cannot comprehend the real issue. Can you please provide the complete components, if possible ?